# How to install Gitlab with Virtualbox and Vagrant on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, github, virtualbox, vagrant

I have no idea How to install Gitlab with Virtualbox and Vagrant on Ubuntu.I am totally lost and getting nothing from the Online Research.

Please Help me..

Thanks And Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do this from scratch, just use the Gitlab Virtualbox image that is provided.

Reference https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/VirtualBox-Image.

Download the Virtualbox image which can be found at http://minus.com/m55CpmY6C/.

Access virtual machine with vagrant:

```bash
vagrant box add gitlab /path/to/the/GITLAB-UBUNTU-SERVER-10.04-I386.box
vagrant init gitlab
vagrant up
```

In the vagrant file:

```ruby
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "gitlab"
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.10"
end
```

To login to vagrant:

```bash
vagrant ssh
```

To restart and upgrade the Gitlab Web Server:

```bash
cp gitlabhq/config/gitlab.yml{.example,}
cp gitlabhq/config/database.yml{.example,}
./restart_and_upgarde_gitlabhq
```

That starts the Gitlab server, and you can login to the Gitlab website at `http://33.33.33.10`

A GitLab admin login is already set up with username "admin@local.host", and password "5iveL!fe".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to get this working. Your answer helped a lot.Thanks again.

Answer (score 12):

GitLab CEO here. You can just install the Omnibus package in your virtual machine, this is 2 minutes of work, see https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/

If you want to have the Omnibus package install automatically there is a community Vagrant option listed on https://about.gitlab.com/installation/

The cookbooks or virtualbox images are no longer supported nor recommended.

Comment: Apparently this cookbook is being deprecated in favour of [cookbook-omibus-gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cookbook-omnibus-gitlab), but as of right now, the readme is rather lackluster.